# Core data lightweight migration - crashes the xcode when added the version

Tags: core-data

My Core Data will update one more attribute and , to avoid crashing , I added a new model version as first, but where can i set the migration options true as my app delegate dont have persistent coordiinator

Comment: You do that in whatever part of your app creates the persistent container. Somewhere, you must be creating it, and that's where you set the migration options.

Comment: I have a persistent container created in my app and I write that code there,thanks this helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Your Core data modeld name")
    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
    description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
    description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
    //--------------------------------------------------------//
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```